# Can't call super when monkeypatching Set#add

Tags: ruby

I want to patch `Set#add` to accept multiple arguments, the same way as with `Array#push`. The following:

```
require 'set'
class Set
  def add(*args)
    args.each { |arg| super arg }
    self
  end
end
s = Set.new
s.add 1,2
```

doesn't work, it raises:

> 'block in add': super: no superclass method `add' for # (NoMethodError)

I don't see why this should be the case, since 
I saw in the [`Set#add`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html#method-i-add) source that it has a standard definition. It's such a simple definition that I can easily get around using `super`:

```
require 'set'
class Set
  def add(*args)
    args.each { |arg| @hash[arg] = true }
    self
  end
end
s = Set.new
s.add 1,2
```

Why doesn't it work to call `super`?

Comment: `Set.ancestors[1..-1].any? { |klass| klass.public_method_defined?(:add) }
 => false`

Comment: This way of monkeypatching is obsolete anyway, with the advent of `Module#prepend`. Read up on it, if you're not familiar. It allows you to amend existing classes __and__ use super. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you override a method, then you're changing its definition. Calling `super` will not work; the original method does *not* still exist as something to forward the message call on to.

There are a few ways to solve this. The "classical" way would be to not override the method at all, and instead define your own **subclass** of `Set`:

```
require 'set'
class MySet < Set
 def add(*args)
    args.each { |arg| super arg }
    self
  end
end
s = MySet.new
s.add 1,2
#=> #<MySet: {1, 2}>
```

...But this may not be ideal since you'll need to reference `MySet` (or whatever you call it) all over the codebase, instead of `Set`.

If you want to modify the behaviour of `Set` directly, then the "old-school" ruby way (*no longer recommended*, as of ruby `v2.0+`) is to  to `alias` the original method to a different name, then create your own version and call the original:

```
require 'set'
class Set
  alias_method :original_add, :add
  def add(*args)
    args.each { |arg| original_add(arg) }
    self
  end  
end
s = Set.new
s.add 1,2
#=> #<Set: {1, 2}>
```

Rails also used to provide a helper method: [`alias_method_chain`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/Module/alias_method_chain), which made it a little easier to perform this common workaround.

But clearly, that's not a great solution since you end up polluting the class with weird methods like `original_<foo>`, or `<foo>_with(out)_<feature>`. Thankfully Ruby 2.0 added a new method: `Module#prepend`, which provides a much cleaner solution to the problem:

```
require 'set'
module AddWithMultipleArgs
  def add(*args)
    args.each { |arg| super arg }
    self
  end
end

class Set
  prepend AddWithMultipleArgs
end

# Or, you can just call:
# Set.prepend(AddWithMultipleArgs)

s = Set.new
s.add 1,2
#=> #<Set: {1, 2}>
```

This works by injecting your new method **before** the original version, in the class' ancestor chain:

```
Set.ancestors
#=> [AddWithMultipleArgs, Set, Enumerable, Object, PP::ObjectMixin, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

Since you never modified the original version of the method, on the `Set` class itself, calling `super` will work as you expect.

Comment: Another option is to patch a single instance via `extend`, e.g. `s.extend(AddWithMultipleArgs)` which also allows `super`.

Comment: "injecting above" - Interesting wording. In your mental image, does the ancestors chain go _down_? In mine, the chain grows from bottom up.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev what do you mean by _"grows from bottom up"_ – in your mental model, is `BasicObject` at the top or at the bottom?

Comment: @Stefan: at the top.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev that aligns with my model. It's also the way family trees and class diagrams are usually drawn – parent / superclass on top, child / subclass below (super = above, sub = under).

Comment: @Stefan: indeed.

Comment: Who said "injecting above"? I said "before" :P Anyway, linguistics aside, the important conceptual point is just to understand where each method is actually defined, and the order of their delegation.

Answer (score 5):

> Why doesn't it work to call `super`?

It is because `Set#add` is defined right on `Set` itself, and not on any of its super classes. And you're overwriting that definition.